# winston rotating log file name includes date of the day

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, rotation, winston

I want to create a rotating log file whose name includes the date of the file.

For example: 25052021-frontendlogs.txt

My application does not restart each day. So programmaticaly naming of the file is not possible.

winston-daily-rotate-file package only supports %DATE% environment variable in file name. Output of the %DATE% is 25-05-2021, there are some "-" in this output that i don't want so i can create a file "25-05-2021-frontendlogs.txt". How can i format the file name as "25052021-frontendlogs.txt"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
let DATE = "20-05-2021";
DATE = DATE.replace(/-/g, '');
console.log(DATE);
```

Comment: I highlighted that my applications does not restart each day. So the code below works once. one day later log file name will be 21-05-2021.

Comment: So you just put your date variable and the above code where you create daily log file.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not possible